# vim command for jumping to <++>

Tags: vimrc, filetype-tex, plugin-vimtex

I recently moved from `vim-latex-suit` to `vimtex`.
In `vim-latex-suit`, there was this awesome feature that when I press `Ctrl-j`, it jumps to where `<++>` is and replace that to the cursor.

To clarify,

I want

```
blah blah blah <++>
```

to be

```
blah blah blah |
```

where `|` is the position of the cursor.

I would like to implement the same feature by some command in `.vimrc`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure:

```
nnoremap <C-j> /\V<++><CR>cgn
" if you want insert-mode versions, too
imap <C-j> <esc><C-j>
```

Or, if you don't want to mess with search history,

```
nnoremap <C-j> :call search('\V<++>')<CR>cf>
" insert-mode
imap <C-j> <esc><C-j>
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried but this answer didn't have the part 
> `<++>` is and replace that to the cursor.
It jumps to where `<++>` is, but it doesn't clear `<++>` and replace that with the cursor

Comment: Try `cgn` after a search. You could alternately start select mode with something like `gh<C-o>//e<CR>`. `cgn` has the advantage that it is (a) dot-repeatable and (b) after invoking the mapping or search, you can just type `cgn` for each instance you want to change.

Comment: nnoremap <C-j> :call search('\V<++>')<CR> cgn ?

Comment: Sans space, but yes! and then further `cgn` will jump to the next, but so will the mapping.

Comment: Yeah the answer is still incomplete. Yes, the first ctrl+j jumps and erases `<++>` and it adds line after second ctrl+j and on instead of jumping to the next one

Comment: @Tom did you try exactly what I put in the edits? The first command worked on everything I tested.

Comment: @Tom perhaps you want to map it in insert mode as well (inoremap). If so,  add <esc> at the start: `inoremap <C-j> <esc>/\V<++><CR>cgn`

Comment: @Biggybi or save yourself some duplication with `:imap <C-j> <esc><C-j>` :)

Comment: @Biggybi I edited the answer and now it does what I want to do! Thank you everyone!